# Error loading PHP file in Symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, require, require-once

I'm trying to load an authentication PHP file in my Symfony controller.

I must use it with `require_once` (can't copy it). It contains a class for identification on my website.

This is what I tried so far:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/login")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    require_once("/usr/share/php/ariseid/client/OAuthAriseClient.php");
    require_once("./config.inc.php");
    $consumer = OAuthAriseClient::getInstance($consumer_key, $consumer_secret,$consumer_private_key);

    $consumer->authenticate();

    if ($consumer->has_just_authenticated()) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $consumer->session_id_changed();
    }

    if ($consumer->is_authenticated()) {
            $results = $consumer->api()->begin()
                    ->get_identifiant()  
                    ->done();

            try { 
                    $_SESSION['AriseID'] = $results[0]();
            }
            catch(OAuthAPIException $e) {
                    echo "Erreur : ".$e->getMessage();
            }
    }
    return $this->render('SlothBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'islogged' => $consumer->is_authenticated(),
        ));
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> CRITICAL - Fatal Error: Class'SlothBundle\Controller\OAuthAriseClient' not found 
>   Context: {"type":1,"file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/src/SlothBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php","line":39,"level":-1,"stack":[{"function":"loginAction","type":"->","class":"SlothBundle\Controller\DefaultController","file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3109,"args":[]},{"function":"call_user_func_array","file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3109,"args":[]},{"function":"handleRaw","type":"->","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel","file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3071,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel","file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3222,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2444,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel","file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/web/app_dev.php","line":29,"args":[]},{"function":"{main}","file":"/home/users/assoces/separatiiste/html/web/app_dev.php","line":0,"args":[]}]}

I tried with composer but it returns the same error.

Comment: require_once ? in Symfony oO this is absurd..
How ever in your case you are in a namespace and if you want to call OAuthAriseClient you have to put slash before it  \OAuthAriseClient ...

Comment: thanks it works can u explain me why ? and if it's absurd i'd like to know why and how correct it. thanks

Comment: You can read for PHP Namespacing at php.net documentation. 
The absurd thing in fact is not really wrong but I can't just explain you :) I am not good teacher..

Comment: Or just use: $consumer = \OAuthAriseClient::  Note the back slash.  That is assuming that your OAuthAriseClient.php files does not have a namespace.  And yes you should read about and understand namespaces.  If OAuthAriseClient is from a third party then look at their website and see how to do a composer install.  Then the includes go away.

Answer (score 1):

What about using composer to load your file?

You just have to make sure those files are accessible and within your project folder (if you want to keep things simple).

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" },
    "files": [
        "ariseid/client/OAuthAriseClient.php",
        "config.inc.php"
    ]
}
```

Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

When using your classes you can either do `use OAuthAriseClient;` on the top of your file and then `OAuthAriseClient::getInstance()` or you can just prepend a backslash to its name `\OAuthAriseClient::getInstance()` when using it.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Anyway, according to the error you're getting this is what I think you should do:

```php
use SlothBundle\Controller\OAuthAriseClient;

// ...

$consumer = OAuthAriseClient::getInstance($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $consumer_private_key);
```

**Note:** If you're going to authenticate the user every time in your controllers consider adding an event listener that authenticates the user before reaching the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not importing the class from the `use` statements,
your controller is looking for a class which is part of the same namespace (`SlothBundle\Controller`).

You have to use your class as follows :

```
$consumer = \OAuthAriseClient::getInstance($consumer_key, $consumer_secret,$consumer_private_key);
```